# Drag-Drop a slide from a custom-taskpane in Powerpoint

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, drag-and-drop, office-interop

I want to drag-drop a slide from a custom task-pane which houses bitmaps corresponding to specific ppt slides. The drop-target needs to be the slide-area, or the slide-index pane on the left. I referred to [this](http://wpftutorial.net/DragAndDrop.html) and a couple other similar articles while going about doing

My question is:
I am able to detect the drag from the task pane. However, I do not have a target-element which allows me to set the "AllowDrop" property, and handle drop-events there.

How do i resolve this?

Comment: have you got the solution for this